# Eclipse Target Platform loading different Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, p2

I am on Windows using eclipse rcp 2020-06 and I have different versions of Target Platforms that I get from a Software Vendor. Sometimes I get an error in eclipse because it seems that the Vendor sometimes has jars with the same name but different contents.

E.g. they have org.quartz_2.1.7.jar but one is 200 KiB and one is 400 KiB.
The target platform I loaded has the 400 KiB one but for some reason the 200 KiB is the one that lands in my .bundle_pool when I add the target platform to eclipse.
This leads to an error when starting because one of the plugins has RequireBundle: org.apache.log4j and the other has org.apache.logging.log4j

This is just an example though. I know that if the Vendor would rename the files if they changed it would probably work but they don't seem to do this.

Could the behavior maybe have something to do with me usually using the Copy Settings (Preferences + Workbench Layout) from File > Switch Workspace > Other... when I create a new Workspace?

Is there any way I can force eclipse to take the plugin that is actually in the target platform I select? I tried deleting ~/.m2/repository/p2 and ~/.p2 but the problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried it on the current release? Yours is 3 years old.

Comment: As workaround for the problem that there are different plugins/bundles with the same symbolic name and same version, you can specify in your target platform from which p2 repository the plugin/bundle should be downloaded. Please show the content of your target platform definition file.

Comment: @howlger unfortunately because of the proprietary license I can not share the complete target platform definition. Can you please tell me which part of which file you want to know the content of? Then I can hopefully give that information here.

Comment: You have to find out which p2 repositories provide this plugin. Be aware that there also [composite repositories](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Composite_Repositories_%28new%29). The [_Repository Explorer_ view](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Oomph_Repository_Explorer) which is included in the [Oomph Targlets](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Oomph_Targlets) might be helpful for that.

Comment: @howlger I have found no duplicates using the Repository Explorer. I use only one repository and it is not composite afaik. For e.g. org.quartz I can find only one unit and it looks like the correct version (declaring dependency on org.apache.logging.log4j and not org.apache.log4j. Full unit of org.quartz; https://pastebin.com/mPzzjgb5
I wonder if it is just a bug in my old eclipse version or maybe it really is just an issue with local caching

Comment: To avoid caching in Maven/Tycho build do the following. Also delete `/.m2/repository/.cache/tycho`. And if this does not help, use a fresh local Maven repository via `-Dmaven.repo.local=...`.

Comment: weirdly I never had the problem with maven/tycho. Only when developing in eclipse and adding the target platform there. If I add a target platform and the issue happens, I can see that the wrong jar file lands in .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\plugins:
I will try deleting the tycho cache next time. Are there any other folders I should pay attention to or are they all basically in ~/.m2 and ~/.p2 ß

Comment: As Maven plugin Tycho uses only `~/.m2`, not `~/.p2`. Where you have this problem, when building with Maven/Tycho or in your Eclipse IDE or in both?

Comment: I only have the problem in eclipse.

Comment: I see. Does this problem persist when using a fresh workspace? Can the faulty plugin also be found somewhere in your Eclipse installation directory (or, if you used the Eclipse Installer, in your user home directory `.p2\pool\plugins`)?

Comment: A fresh workspace using the same target platform yields the same issue.  I couldn't find anything in my eclipse installation directory.
It is worth noting that the target platform is not some form of eclipse IDE, but an eclipse rcp/rap target platform. I don't know if that matters though

Comment: Please check whether the plugin is part of your Eclipse IDE or not: _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_, tab _Plug-ins_ and filter for `quartz`.

Comment: It is not part of my Eclipse IDE

Comment: Okay, but it has to come from somewhere. And from what you say, it doesn't occur with Maven/Tycho, which also uses the same target platform, right? It also happens with a fresh workspace and is not part of your Eclipse installation. I have no idea where else it could come from.

Comment: I have no clue where the issue comes from sadly. Thank you anyway for your help